# 'Generic hook <name> is deprecated' warning after update

Tags: warnings, updating, hooks, lthooks

I have had a warning for a few days (since I updated MiKTeX):

```
LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook
(hooks)              'file/after/translations-basic-dictionary-french.trsl' is
(hooks)              deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook
(hooks)              'file/translations-basic-dictionary-french.trsl/after'
(hooks)              instead.
```

Is there a (simple) way to solve this?

Comment: show a small, complete example so that we can identify the package.

Comment: The warning is harmless.  It is due to a recent change in the LaTeX kernel, and it should be fixed as soon as `translations` is updated.  I opened an issue some time ago: https://github.com/cgnieder/translations/issues/18

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for an update, then.

Answer (score 29):

Warnings of the form:

```
LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'file/after/<name>' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'file/<name>/after' instead.
```

are due to a [recent change](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/656) in the LaTeX kernel in which we normalised generic hooks to have the variable part in the middle, because we had `env/<name>/after` and `file/after/<name>` which was simply confusing.  Now the `file`, `package`, `class`, and `include` hooks have the same form as other hooks: `file/<name>/after`.

To avoid complete breakage of thousands of documents (including yours, dear reader), the old hook names will be available for a while, until packages (like `translations`) have time to adjust.  The warning is just there as a reminder, but it is completely harmless for your document, so there is nothing to worry about (except maybe ask the package author for an update :).

---

Just for the sake of discoverability by search engines, similar warnings will be:

```
LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/after/<name>' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/<name>/after' instead.
```

```
LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'class/after/<name>' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'class/<name>/after' instead.
```

```
LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'include/after/<name>' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'include/<name>/after' instead.
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't manage, for now, to discover the package responsible for this

Comment: @Didier What do you mean?  The package using the incorrect hook name, in your case, is `translations`

Comment: Ok. I tried to comment all my packages and the problem seems to come from pstricks-add (if I put a % in front of \usepackage{pstricks-add}, the warning disappears). I don't use `translations` but maybe pstricks-add calls it?

Comment: @Didier Yes, `pstricks-add` uses (`pst-math`, which uses `pst-calculate`, which uses `siunitx`, which uses) `translations`.  But I don't think you should worry about removing that warning:  as I said, it's harmless, although annoying (both by design :).  If you _really_ want to remove the warning, then add `\ExplSyntaxOn \msg_redirect_name:nnn { hooks } { generic-deprecated } { none } \ExplSyntaxOff` to your preamble

Comment: Thank you for your help. This warning is a little annoying but never mind. I will wait for an update

Comment: @Didier Sorry about that (I wrote the warning code :)

Comment: Just to clarify, the package named in the warning message is the one that needs to be updated with the newly renamed hooks, correct? I'm currently getting them for `amsmath`, `mathtools`, and `icomma`. I think they're loaded by `unicode-math` but I haven't confirmed that yet.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL No, the package that needs updating is the one that _adds_ to the hook (in this case `unicode-math`), because it's that package that is using the deprecated hook name.  A more helpful warning would include that information, but it's not easy to determine the name of the criminal programatically, so we have what we have

Comment: For the record, I discovered that the warnings I'm seeing are due to `lualatex-math` loading the `amsmath`, `mathtools`, and `icomma` packages. `unicode-math` is not the culprit.

Comment: For the record, today's `lualatex-math` update fixed the problem.