# How to use Silence package to silence hooks warning

Tags: pdftex, hooks

When I run the following .tex source file through latex:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,article]{memoir}
\begin{document}
  Hi
\end{document}
```

I get the following warning:

```
...

(/usr/local/texlive/2021basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty)

LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/before/framed' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/framed/before' instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)

LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/before/float' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/float/before' instead.

)

...
```

According to [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623542/generic-hook-name-is-deprecated-warning-after-update), this is a harmless warning; but unfortunately it pops up a warning every time compile a LaTeX file in my editor—which basically changes the error from being an annoyance to making continuous compile unusable.  I would like to suppress this warning using the silence package[2](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/silence), but cannot figure out how to do it.  Here is what I have added to my preamble:

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Generic hook}
```

I have tried many variations on this, but with no success.  I have also tried the solution at [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623542/generic-hook-name-is-deprecated-warning-after-update) (in comments to answer, starting with `\ExplSyntaxOn`) to no avail.  Does anyone have a way to suppress this warning?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! 1) Yes, the warning is harmless (I wrote it). 2) It's not an error, so it can't make "compile unusable" (unless your editor is doing something weird). 3) _Please_ don't use `silence`. Ever. 4) `\ExplSyntaxOn \msg_redirect_name:nnn { hooks } { generic-deprecated } { none } \ExplSyntaxOff` before `\documentclass` should silence the warning, but as I said it's harmless and you shouldn't bother about it

Comment: Thank you.  And putting `\ExplSyntaxOn` before `\documentclass` fixed things.  Can I ask, why not ever use `silence`?  I find I get certain warnings — such as BibLatex saying "Package biblatex Warning: Since you are using the 'memoir' class, I'm leaving the formatting of the foot- and/or end-note mark and text to you.." — which I am aware of, and have taken care of; so I use `silence` to stop it constantly telling me this.  Is there some better solution?

Comment: I'm also curious why warnings should not be silenced as a matter of principle "ever". I often silence messages -- the problem is that un-needed warnings are not benign - they make it hard to address and detect the needed ones when they exist in a barrage.

Comment: @CuriousYogurt Point 3 was more of an opinion than an instruction :)  The problem is not silencing warnings _per se_ (I just told you how to silence one), but the first issue is that people often misuse `silence` to silence a message they shouldn't (not your case, I know).  The second issue is that because of how `silence` patches itself into LaTeX error messaging mechanism, it often breaks things in mysterious and hard-to-debug way, so as a matter of principles I preach against it.  You are totally free to ignore me, of course :)

Comment: @CuriousYogurt Also, most warnings allow some polite way to make them shut up.  For example, the BibLaTeX-memoir warning you mentioned can be turned off by loading `biblatex-chicago` with the option `footmarkoff`.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn See comments above

Comment: @CuriousYogurt By the way, I already contacted the `memoir` maintainer and he has already changed the hook names, so as soon as the update is live, the two warnings in your question will cease

Comment: @CuriousYogurt You helped a lot by only loading `memoir` in your example (so thanks!)  Then I looked at the log to find out where the warning occurred.  When a file is opened, TeX writes, say, `(/path/to/memoir.cls` then when that file is closed, it writes a matching `)`, then you just have to find which was the most recent unclosed file.  Then to make sure, I browsed the code in `memoir.cls` and found `package/before/#1`, which is the name the warning is complaining about

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ah, I understand.  And thank you for the tip about biblatex-chicago.

Comment: @CuriousYogurt Glad it helped ;-) Do you mind if mark this question to close as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/623542/134574?